# Не получается отредактировать сообщение aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, asyncio

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.image)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️ 0%")

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['description'] = message.text + " --upbeta"
        data['description_translated'] = testyt.translate(message.text) + " --upbeta"
        data['completed_image_data'] = testreal.main(data['description_translated'])

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.edit_text("⚪️⚪️⚪️⚫️ 25%")

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.edit_text("⚪️⚪️⚫️⚫️ 50%")

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.edit_text("⚪️⚫️⚫️⚫️ 75%")

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.edit_text("⚫️⚫️⚫️⚫️ 100%")

    testrwatermark.watermark(data['description_translated'] + '.jpg', "proof")
    photo = open(data['description_translated'] + '_watermarked.png', 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)

    await message.answer("Можете выбрать вариант, который вам больше всего понравился? ", reply_markup=greet_kb)
    await Form.image2.set()
```

Ошибка

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-17' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=MessageCantBeEdited("Message can't be edited")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\main\main.py", line 154, in process_name
    await message.edit_text("⚪️⚪️⚪️⚫️ 25%")
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\message.py", line 2919, in edit_text
    return await self.bot.edit_message_text(
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 3122, in edit_message_text
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.EDIT_MESSAGE_TEXT, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited
```